# app global property doesnt work when used inside script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am using `Lang` plugin. This is how I install it:

```
onDomReady(() => {
  appVue.use(Lang, {
     lang: langService._lang,
  });
  appVue.mount('#app');
});
```

And this is install code for `Lang`:

```
const plugin = {
  install(app, options) {
    if (!app.config.globalProperties.hasOwnProperty('$lang')) {
      app.config.globalProperties.$lang = options.lang;
    }

    app.config.globalProperties.$t = function (key, opt) {
      const lang = this.$lang;
      return lang.trans(key, opt);
    };
  },
};

export default plugin;
```

So now I should be able to access `$t` and `$t` works when it is used inside `template` tags for example.

```
<template>
 <div>{{ $t('hello') }}<div>
<template>
```

It prints out translation, but when I use inside `<script>` tag for example:

```
props: {
   placeholder: {
     type: String,
     default() {
      return this.$t('hello');
     },
   }
}
```

It throws me error `this.$t is not a function`. What is the problem here? Would appreciate some help

Comment: hey mate, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917711/vue3-use-global-variable-in-js-files) pls

Comment: Didnt help. What I found out that inside `created()` or `mounted()` `this.$t` works. But inside props it doesnt work.

Comment: The problem is that `$t` is not yet injected into your component when Vue clones the prop values before instantiating your component - the component does not exist at this moment of time so `this` points to nowhere. If you need default values for uninitialized props - compose them in the template, e.g. `<div>{{ placeholder || $t('hello') }}</div>` or perhaps even use a computed property for cleaner template.

Comment: Yea something similar I did