# How to use Vue js global variables in pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuejs3, pinia

I have a Vue.js 3 project where I want to use a global axios instance in some .vue components and also in a pinia store.

My main.js file has axios globally configured like this

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$http = axiosInstance;
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);

//other code...
```

In .vue components I can axios via `$http` just fine like this.

```
methods: {
    async debug() {
      const response = await this.$http.get("get-dates");
      console.log(response.data);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use `this.$http` in a pinia store it is undefined. I also noticed that all global variables like $route are all undefined as well.

```
export const useDateStore = defineStore("dateStore", {
    state: () => ({
        allowedDates: []
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchAvailableDates() {
            //how I normally use axios
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/get-dates");
            //how I want to use axios
            const response2 = await this.$http.get("get-dates");

            console.log(this.$http); //gives undefined
        }
});
```

Comment: hey mate, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917711/vue3-use-global-variable-in-js-files) please

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889690/vue-3-accessing-vue-instance-in-vue-router-outside-a-vue-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pinia, you don't have access to global properties. but it's possible to pass using the use()

You will need to change the pinia code and add the context

```
  actions: {
    async fetchAvailableDates() {
      const response = await this.$http.get("get-dates");
      console.log(response.data);
    }
  }
```

On the main.js pass the properties, like this:

```
const pinia = createPinia();
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.$http = app.config.globalProperties.$http;
});
app.use(pinia);
```

and use that you you want

Comment: It's this.$http and not context.$http. Action params are the arguments that are passed to them

Comment: That fixed it for me. The context parameter does not to get passed to actions tho, as said by @EstusFlask. Thank you so much!